# Named entities in encapsulated XML cause parsing errors

Tags: xml, perl, named-entity-recognition

I have XML docs that contain other XML docs encapsulated as CDATA, like this:

```
    <mds>
      <md>
        <value>
          <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
             <dc:title>some text containing &amp;</dc:title></record>]]>
        </value>
      </md>
    </mds>
```

I extract this XML and the dc:title from it using LibXML:

```
$dcrawData = <get the CDATA from above>;
$dcDOM = $::PRSR->load_xml(expand_entities => 0, string => $dcRawData);
$dcTitle = $dcDOM->findvalue("//dc:title");
```

Then I insert it into another XML section by doing a string replace:

```
<mods:titleInfo>
    <mods:title>some text containing &</mods:title>
</mods:titleInfo>
```

As you can see, the &amp entity gets expanded and becomes a single &. Which is a problem because now, the resulting XML generates a parsing error because any parser expects a named entity here.

Is there a way to prevent LibXML from expanding named entities when using findvalue or to reencode them before using the value? There might be others in other records. The expand_entities option does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a solution. [`XML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Entities) will do the job of re-encoding the entities in the string.

However, I need to limit the characters that are encoded to only a few, otherwise the encoded string will have entities that the xml parser does not recognize.

So at the moment I use

```
$dcTitle = encode_entities($dcDOM->findvalue("//dc:title"),'&<>"');
```

to only encode the ampersand and a few special xml chars.

Comment: Given the value you're working with won't contain any element tags, escaping just `&` and `<` should be sufficient to guarantee a well-formed output (if you save the resulting file in the right encoding).

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'll consider that. I don't know the data intimately but it looks like there will only be text in various languages (utf-8) and some unfortunate stuff like the ampersand.

Comment: `findvalue` will never give you elements - it does `to_literal` on whatever the XPath expression returns, so in this case it'll give you a single string containing the concatenation of the string values (i.e. the text content) of all the `dc:title` elements in the document you're looking at.

Comment: @Ian: You're right. And at other places in my project I do go the findnodes-route to avoid having multiple elements joined in one findvalue. But in this instance, there will be only one title and no need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I insert it into another XML section by doing a string replace

Don't. If you want to insert data into an XML document then you should do so using an XML-aware API that will handle any necessary escaping for you.

Comment: Yes,I realize this. But that would mean to throw away a very, very complicated script for a data migration project and rebuilding everything from scratch, introducing a load of other problems that come with building complex XML with DOM... namespace and prefix handling, element ids that are referenced inside the doc are just what comes to mind instantly. You are right of course that this would be the right way to do it.

Comment: @jackthehipster fair enough, given that larger context I'd probably do the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I insert it into another XML section by doing a string replace

This is the part you are doing wrong. You are inserting text into XML without turning it into XML. (This is called an injection error.) You need to escape `&`, `<` and any characters outside the document's character set.

```
sub text_to_xml {
   my ($s) = @_;
   for ($s) {
      s/&/&amp;/g;
      s/</&lt;/g;
      s/"/&quot;/g;  # So it can be used for attributes too
      s/'/&apos;/g;  # So it can be used for attributes too
   }
   return $s;
}
```

Don't forget that you'll also need to encode it according to the document's encoding.

Comment: See my answer above. I'm doing the exact same thing now by using XML::Entities::encode_entities().